# Parsing string with two captures in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to parse a string with regex. A valid string is of the following format:

```
https://github.com/xyz/abc/a_123/project_14.git
```

The valid string should contain `github.com` and `xyz` or `zyx`. If the string is valid I want to capture `abc/a_123` into `$A` and `project_14` into `$B`.

What I did:

```
if [[ "$x" == *"github.com"* ]]; then
    if [[ "$x" == *"xyz"* ]]; then
        # (1)
    elif [[ "$x" == *"zyx"* ]]; then
        # (2)
    else
        return 1 # Invalid
    fi
    return 0 # Valid
fi
return 1 # Invalid
```

In both `(1)` and `(2)` I want to set `$A` and `$B` with the values (same behavior on different cases).
Also, I think that this solution is not good because it will enter the if-else in the case of `https://github.com/bla/abc/a_123/xyz.git` so I guess we need to change it to be `"github.com/xyz"`. Also, how can I get rid of `.git` (if exists)?

Another example:

```
https://github.com/zyx/asdasdas/lalal/asdas/nu.git
# $A = asdasdas/lalal/asdas
# $B = nu
```

What is the proper way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Look up the bash `=~` regex operator. It'll let you do more sophisticated matching than `==`, and it can capture variables. It saves them in an array called `$BASH_REMATCH` -- another good search term.

Comment: A good start can be ```[[ $url =~ http[s]?:[/]{2}(github.com)[/]([[:alpha:]]+)/([[:alpha:]]+)/.*([.]git)?$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}``` and then you will have the matches as indexes of ```${BASH_REMATCH}``` as you can see.

Comment: `sed` and `awk` can be useful friends for cases where you want to check a regex and extract part of string.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using regex:

```
url='https://github.com/xyz/abc/a_123/project_14.git'

if [[ $url =~ http[s]?:[/]{2}(github.com)[/]([[:alpha:]]+)(/.*)$ ]] 
then    
    $A=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    $B=${BASH_REMATCH[3]%.git}
fi
```

And here is a small proof of concept:

```
url='https://github.com/xyz/abc/a_123/project_14.git'

if [[ $url =~ http[s]?:[/]{2}(github.com)[/]([[:alpha:]]+)(/.*)$ ]]
then
   echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]%.git}
fi
```

Resulting in:

```
xyz /abc/a_123/project_14
```

Comment: It will match with `https://github.com/bla/abc/a_123/xyz.git` which the OP want to exclude, won't it?

Comment: It will but as far I understand, that what OP intended, if we have an way to remove the suffix ```.git``` after. And we have, as is shown on my answer.

Comment: Sorry if I may have been unclear, but my concern is  the substring `github.com/` is followed by `bla`, not `xyz` or `zyx`.

Comment: Oh! I see. As I understand OP used that as a generic example but I may have got that wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want :

```
#!/bin/bash

repo="https://github.com/xyz/abc/a_123/project_14.git"

[[ ! "$repo" =~ https:\/\/github.com\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]_[0-9]+\/.*.git ]] && exit

A=$( echo "$repo" | sed -E "s/(https:\/\/github.com\/[a-z]+)(\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]_[0-9]+\/)(.*.git)/\2/g" )
B=$( echo "$repo" | sed -E "s/(https:\/\/github.com\/[a-z]+)(\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]_[0-9]+\/)(.*.git)/\3/g" )

echo "$A"
echo "${B%%.git}"
```

Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
strchk() {
    local x=$1
    if [[ $x =~ github.com/(xyz|zyx)/(.+)/(.+) ]]; then
        A="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        B="${BASH_REMATCH[3]%.*}"
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Results:

```
strchk "https://github.com/xyz/abc/a_123/project_14.git" && echo "A=$A, B=$B"
=> A=abc/a_123, B=project_14
strchk "https://github.com/bla/abc/a_123/xyz.git" && echo "A=$A, B=$B"
=> <empty>
strchk "https://github.com/zyx/asdasdas/lalal/asdas/nu.git" && echo "A=$A, B=$B"
=> A=asdasdas/lalal/asdas, B=nu
```

Explanations:

- The pattern `github.com/(xyz|zyx)/` matches a string which contains
  `github.com/` followed by `xyz/` or `zyx/`.
- The next pattern `(.+)/` matches a substring after `xyz/` or `zyx/` as long
  as it reaches the rightmost slash then stores the captured substring within the parens into
  a bash variable `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`.
- The last pattern `(.+)` captures the remaining substring into
  `${BASH_REMATCH[3]}`.
- The parameter expansion `${BASH_REMATCH[3]%.*}` removes the extension
  after the dot if exists.

Hope this helps.